# How to create a like button with node js express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im building a web page with node,express and mongodb.
Im trying to make a like button, but the problem is I cant pass a variable value from my ejs to my server side. how can I do that? here's what I've tried
Exemple

```
Html
 <div class="thumbnail">
           <div class="caption">
                  <strong  id="Title"><%=video.title %> </strong>
               <button id="like" value="Like" type="submit"> 
              <script>
                     var videoId =<%= video._id %>;
                 $('#like').click(function(){
                 $.post('/like/'+videoId);
               });
            </script>
```

Server side

```
    router.post('/like/:videoId', function (req, res) {
    var test = req.params.videoId;
    console.log("works");
    console.log(test);

     });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: which version express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST-parameters are sent in the request body. To recieve a parameter from a POST-request you would need a body-parser and then grab it with `req.body.videoId`.

If you want to grab a parameter from the URL, like you are trying to do here, you should use a GET-request instead. Then you will be able to grab the id with `req.params.videoId`.

So simply change the jQuery from POST to GET and change to `router.get` on the server side and it should work.

Further reading: [How are parameters sent in POST-request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)